# Please suggest other ways of communicating between server & client

Tags: language-agnostic, network-programming, client-server

I'm writing a TCP chat server ( programming language does not mather ). It's a school project for my nephew, so it won't be released, and all questions I'm asking are just for my knowledge :). . Some of the things it will support:

- chatting between users ( doh ), it will be multithreaded
- sending each other files

I know I could easily get away with all the stuff above if I go with serialization, and just send objects from client to server and back. But, if I do that, it will be limited to a specific programming language ( meaning clients written in other programming languages may not be able to deserialize the objects ). What would be the way to go so that other clients written in other languages could be supported?

One way to go, off the top of my head, would be to go in this direction: the server & the client communicate by sending messages & chunks ( in lieu of other names ). Here's what I mean by this:

- every time the client/server wants to send something ( text message or file ) it will first send a simple text message ( newline terminated ) with the number of the chunks it will send. Example:

  command 4,20,30,40,50

Where `command` would be something like `instant-message` or `file`,4 would be the number of chunks to be sent, 20 would be the size in bytes of the first chunk, 30 of the 2nd, and so forth.

- after the message was sent, the client/server will start sending chunks ( of sizes mentioned in the sent message ).

What do you think about implementing the client/server communication this way? What better options are there?

Comment: TCP/IP over Avian Carrier, as per RFC 1149: http://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1149.txt

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you say about serialization isn't true. You can use a cross-platform serialization protocol, like [protocol buffers](http://code.google.com/intl/el/apis/protocolbuffers/docs/overview.html). This will make your life easier and save you from implementing your own communication protocol. In my opinion it will be better to find an existing protocol and implement this instead of trying to make your own. Something as simple as [xmodem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMODEM) could do.

Also to avoid client software having to act both as server and as client (meaning having to solve peer identification issues), you could have all clients communicating through a centralized server.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds fine, basically you need to define a message header (as you have done) so that a receiver will know how many bytes to read for each message.

I suggest placing a message size as the first parameter instead of a variable-length command string. That way there is no ambiguity in case the command happens to arrive across 2 separate TCP packets.

Answer (score 1):

I might pass XML between the clients; that'd work.

For passing files, perhaps just pass a byte buffer; only problem there is if you're going between high endian and low endian machines, I think.

Comment: In fall of 2003, a classmate of mine in a graduate systems modelling class did a simulation study.  The result was that using XML to encapsulate data was good for two orders of magnitude of performance hit.  The problem is that, when you take all the coding into effect, XML tends to wrap about 800 bits (100 bytes) of verbiage around every actual 8 bits (1 byte) of actual data.

Comment: @John R. Strohm: Create your own DTD, and keep it short.  I've found that most of the heavily verbose XML DTDs are a disaster, but <m from="asdf">This is the message</m> would be valid, as would <m from="asdf" type="file">a7x@dz...</m>

Answer (score 1):

A pretty typical solution here is Web Services using SOAP.

Answer (score 1):

Silly question: Why not use TELNET protocol over TCP/IP for the chat stream, and something like FTP over TCP/IP for file transfers?